# Subdomain folder redirect not working after SSL cert applied

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, subdomain, cpanel

I'm having a small issue with cpanel subdomain folder redirecting after the application of a wildcard SSL certificate for the domain.

The setup is:

- Wordpress site is hosted in the root folder (public_html) of the site, and is accessible via the domain name (site.org).
- Another site is located in a sub folder of public_html (a codeigniter based PHP application), and is accessible via 2 subdomains that map to the folder via cpanel. (crm.site.org, and members.site.org)

The problem is, after application of the SSL certificate, navigating to https://crm.site.org, and https://members.site.org now direct to the Wordpress site in the root directory, and throw a 404 error saying page not found.

It appears that after applicatin of the SSL certificate, the subdomains do not properly get directed to the specified subfolder.

I have tinkered with the .htaccess files in both directories, but have not had any luck in finding a proper configuration.  The .htaccess file in the Wordpress directory is just the plain one that comes with the installation,and the .htaccess in the subfolder very bare bones, and just redirects to index.php (much like the Wordpress one).

Has anyone experienced anything like this before? Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The issue here was that the SSL certificate was only applied to the single domain (site.org) and not each individual subdomain. This was causing any secure connection to be routed to site.org due to the fact that there was only one single SSL virtual host configured in Apache.  Applying the certificate to both subdomains individually gave them the proper virtual host and solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to write .htaccess code to exclude your crm and members directory. I think you are getting this issues due to .htaccess default code so if you exclude that from .htaccess code, then your site https://crm.site.org, and https://members.site.org will be work without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

The SSL certificate for the root may not be configured in the .htaccess in the subdirectory. E.g. https://example.com works but not https://example.com/wordpress

I had a folder in html_public called wordpress and there was a `.htaccess` that I modified and commented out the rewrite conditions - my DNS had blog.example.com pointing at example.com/wordpress and the SSL certificate was installed for blog.example.com but didn't match the example.com certificate.

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com$ [OR]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.blog\.example\.com$
#RewriteRule ^/?$ "example\.com\/wordpress\/index\.php" [R=301,L]
```

Commenting this out tells Apache to use the root certificate at example.com instead. Now SSL works.